# Proving a polynomial has at least 2 distinct roots.

Tags: real-analysis

If $ a,b,c\in\mathbb{R} $ and $ a,c >0$ and we define $p(x)=ax^{14}+bx^5+cx$ then how can we show that $p(x)$ has at least two distinct roots?

I feel like we have to use the IVT but have no idea how to get started - a pointer would be great!

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* One root is $0$. Remove that and we're left with a polynomial of odd degree, which has a real root.

Comment: This is the necessary insight I think.

Answer (score 0):

If a polynomial has all coincident roots $x= \zeta$ then it has the form
$$p(x)=a(x-\zeta)^{14}$$
As your polynomial has not this form then it has at least two distinct roots

If we want two *real* distinct root then see the answer of @lhf

Collect $x$ and get $p(x)=x(ax^{13}+bx^5+c)$

At this point you have a root $x=0$ and at least another root from $q(x)=ax^{13}+bx^5+c$

Indeed a polynomial with real coefficients and odd degree has at least a real root because as $a>0$ we have $q(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$ and $q(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$ thus for IVT there is at least an $x\ne 0$ such that $p(x)=0$

Hope this helps

Comment: I think the OP means *real* roots.

Comment: @lhf If $\zeta=0$ the polynomial is $P(x)=ax^{14}$...

Comment: @lhf OK, but I am not a fortune teller

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense, I didn't think to factorise the x out, but it's straightforward to apply IVT after that :)